# KeyError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib' in spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, spyder

I'm starting to learn Kivy (hoping it is a good idea!) and I wanted to use some matplotlib graphs in it. The examples I have found use for instance

```py
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas,\
                                                NavigationToolbar2Kivy
```

which leads to the Error **KeyError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib'**

or

```py
from kivy.ext.mpl.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg as FigureCanvas
```

which leads to **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.ext'**

How can I cure this problem? (I'm [infortunatly] using Anaconda, and on macOs Mojave, with the following version of Kivy :

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
```

Comment: Are you sure the matplotlib extension is installed. Can you run something like `garden search | grep mat` and see if it is there?

Comment: @lee-pai-long : it gives me ```Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/garden", line 223, in <module>
     GardenTool().main(sys.argv[1:])
   File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/garden", line 90, in main
     if self.options.kivy and garden_kivy_dir is None:
 AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'kivy'```

Comment: You need to check your installation or recreate your virtualenv if you in one. Make sure you have kivy and garden properly installed. Then install matplotlib using garden, then you should be able to import it.

Comment: @lee-pai-long : all right! I just did ```garden install matplotlib```and now it is working fine for the first one. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't install Spyder and Matplotlib with conda and Kivy with pip because they are incompatible. Since (I guess) there are no conda packages for Kivy, you need to install eveything with pip.